# How to integrate CXF web Services in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, cxf

I'm curious about how node.js is integrate with third party services. Can anybody guide me step by step to integrate CXF services in node.js.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Swagger for a reference on using node.js within CXF.  As you might know already, Swagger allows for documenting your REST CXF services.  There is a project called swagger-ui which will build a web page that allows testing of each of your REST CXF services.  The swaggerui utility uses node.js to build the necessary .json files, each file representing your REST CXF service.  Example: ConfigServiceImpl would have a ConfigService.json file that the node.js server uses for interaction with the swagger-ui testing page.  I have this implemented and it is very nice.